# How to update a single column of a table of data from a backup

Tags: sql, crash, backup

All the data in a column of a table of members have been erased, but I made a backup of the table a few weeks ago.

So I need to replace only the data in this column by the old column in the backup of my table.

The problem is that I do not know how I should proceed to do so.

Have you been confronted by this problem and can you explain it to me

Comment: What kind of database? SQL Server? Oracle? SQLite?

Comment: And next question will be: What kind of back-up, a sql file, csv file, full database back-up etc. There are so many options here.  

At first it would be a smart start to import the full back-up into an empty database to see whether the data is ok there. Then you might script the updates. That could be a simple script but be aware that you need to do some echo's of changes you make and make it possible to run a test first. Also back-up your database before doing such a thing since you might destroy another table.

Comment: As Luc said, first backup the current data so you don't do more harm.  I would restore the backup table to a new table in the database.  Then you should be able to do an update/select to move the column from the backup table to the current table.

Comment: @SteveWellens answer is probably the most universal solution. Other databases have different more granular restore solutions however but may not be worth the trouble of learning if this is small database.

Answer (score 5):

1. Restore the backup of your table as a temporary table.
2. Use a [UPDATE statement](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/update.php) with select to update your members table

Which one of these steps are you having difficulty with?

Here is how I would write the SQL to update my members table from a "members_temp" table

```
 UPDATE members SET name=(select name from members_temp where members.id = members_temp.id)
```

Comment: Is it possible to add an alias to the names like m1 for members and m2 for members_temp in an update statement like this?